# Has Star Trek ever portrayed a culture/location on Earth besides North America and Europe?

Tags: star-trek, geography

The out-of-universe reasons Star Trek is not as diverse as Earth overall are obvious.
But it has always striven to be.

Yet if I think about all the places portrayed on Earth, they are overwhelmingly in North America (and Europe).

Are there any counterexamples?

Some locations on Earth which come to mind off the top of my head:

- San Francisco (Starfleet Academy, 19th century Guinan, *Star Trek IV*)
- New York (*TOS*: "The City on the Edge of Forever")
- New Orleans (various episodes related to Sisko men)
- Iowa (young Kirk)
- London (*Star Trek Into Darkness*)
- France (Picard's vineyard, Federation President's Office)
- Los Angeles (*Voyager* "Future's End")
- Nevada (*DS9* "Little Green Men")
- Pennsylvania (*ENT* "Carbon Creek")
- Montana (*Star Trek: First Contact*)
- "The Arctic" (*ENT*: Regeneration) -- based on the names of the researchers, I'm going to assume this is Alaska or Canada, but at any rate, there is no other Earth culture here
- Florida (*ENT* Xindi incident)

**Clarification**:   Portrayal means an actual on-Earth scene occurs in a location.

Comment: Does "portrayed" mean actually appear on screen?  In the Xindi incident, we see Florida from space only, I believe.

Comment: @Praxis:   Portrayal means appear onscreen.   I thought Tucker visited Florida, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You could be right!

Comment: @Praxis:  [Reed and Tucker look for any sign that his sister might be alive in Xindi-devastated Florida](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/30/TuckerReedFloridaCloseup.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070918034258&path-prefix=en)

Comment: Ah, yes --- thanks. :-)

Comment: TOS: The City on the Edge of Forever and several ENT episodes show the [Gizeh pyramids](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Pyramid). However, this is all through   Guardians of Forever and other timeywimey tricks; basically they appear on a "screen" in the scene. Not sure if this counts.

Comment: Related, revealing, sometimes sort of funny (amazing how *limited* the entire franchise has been): [Filming Locations](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Filming_locations)

Comment: I'm sure I saw this before but it's not here anymore, but do holodeck recreations count?  I'm pretty sure you specified before they weren't, but do they count now?

Comment: @TheDoc, probably not.   What do you have in mind.   Maybe for a holodeck version of something contemporary.  Or if it's not highly fictional.

Comment: @ThePopMachine there's a holodeck scene set in the Himalayas so not sure if that would count?

Comment: @TheDoc, ds9 spy show?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yep that's the one!  You probably shouldn't accept holodeck recreations, as that could make the question very broad, but thought I'd just clarify

Comment: Does Central America count? If so, the Rubber Tree People of "Tatoo" (VOY 2x09) would be the perfect answer.

Comment: @StefanWalter, I don't think a fictional culture,  far from Earth, counts

Comment: @ThePopMachine: What do you mean, far from Earth? They're an Indian tribe on Earth that was influenced by aliens long ago. Anyway, I didn't comment to win a prize or anything, but because I thought you were genuinely interested.

Comment: @StefanWalter, okay, my mistake.   But we're still talking about an imaginary culture,  right?

Comment: The name of that particular tribe was of course fictional, and they were a bit too magical to be realistic. But I think they were intended as a (probably not very accurate) example of real Central or Southern American tribes.

Comment: Don't forget Florida (Cape Canaveral) in TOS _Assignment: Earth_.

Comment: I think the choice of location has a great deal more to do with economics of making TV rather than  anything else.  Its a lot cheaper to film in USA rather than having to make a set depicting an Russian environment for example

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes, this girl in this scene.

In a flashback seen in *TNG* "[Violations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Violations_(episode))", we see Keiko Ishikawa interacting with a Japanese cup used to wash calligraphy brushes by her [Obachan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Obachan)(grandmother).   This is clearly Japanese culture.  And it almost certainly occurs in Japan.

In "Emissary":

> O'BRIEN: When my wife Keiko saw our quarters, she started talking about visiting her mother in Kumamoto

While not conclusive, there's no indication the scene is not in Japan, and her mother (still) apparently lives there.

[image][image]

Comment: "Portrayal means an actual on-Earth scene occurs in a location." - are you sure this scene is actually meant to take place in Japan?

Comment: +1...definitely a non-European cultural portrayal.  But I'm not sure about the location of the scene.  The dialogue doesn't explicitly say it occurs in Japan (http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/212.htm)...it could have happened anywhere on 24th Century Earth, for all we know.

Comment: @randal'thor : Did you borrow N_Soong's synaptic scanner while I was away?  ;-)

Comment: This is a flashback to her young childhood (you can see her hands) with her grandmother.   [She was a native of Japan.](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Keiko_O%27Brien)   It's a very safe assumption.

Comment: From "Emissary" we know her mother (still?) lives in Kumamoto.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Fair point.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I wasn't meaning to send you down the technicality road (I myself try to veer away from that sort of thing).  I just felt the Japan location remark needed independent confirmation.  I think your "Emissary" reference about Kumamoto is worth putting in your answer. :-)

Answer (score 34):

In the first episode of Enterprise, Capt. Archer travels to Brazil to persuade Hoshi Sato to leave her teaching post early to join the crew of the Enterprise.  She is shown teaching a language class outdoors in a heavily wooded area.

[image]

Comment: Good addition! I took the liberty to add a picture from Memory Alpha.

Answer (score 33):

In *Voyager*'s first episode, [**"Caretaker"**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Caretaker_(episode)), Janeway fetches Tom Paris from the **Federation Penal Colony in New Zealand**.

[image]

Comment: @randal'thor : Hehe, thanks!  Thought I'd try my hand at it again.  And I see that you are still continuing to hone your own Star Trek skills!  :-D

Comment: Great find; had totally forgotten that!  Here, have a +1

Comment: Yes, this is a valid answer.   I'm still a little disappointed that it's just Paris and Janeway in a forest and that New Zealand is still essentially a culture of European origin.   Anything else?

Comment: http://www.backpackerguide.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/maori.jpg I think they might disagree about the European origin, and I sure hope that by the 24th century, they would have regained equal rights and status!

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I was going to say something similar to Joerg --- New Zealand is a non-North America, non-European location with a culture that predates European contact.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, while technically true, this is neither here nor there.   Just like there are indigenous peoples in North America.   Unless and until you can demonstrate that somehow the Maori have taken over as the dominant culture in New Zealand in the 24th century, the smart money's on the assumption that New Zealand's primary culture is of European origin.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Is the question to be read as "culture and/or location" or as "culture or location"?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : In fairness, we don't really see a European or a non-European culture at work in "Caretaker". We just see a pretty comfortable, outdoor prison.

Comment: @Praxis:   Well, the best answer would one that was both.   I have one.   Hang on!

Comment: @ThePopMachine consider that Earth in Star Trek is a very globalised place; it would be challenging to find any culture when there is not at least some Western influence

Comment: @TheDoc, I'm not saying no influence.   Has there been a shot of a restaurant in India?  A town in China?  A Starfleet facility in Nairobi?  Anything?

Comment: Don't the writers of the show know that Australia was the penal colony?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm : Apparently not... ;-)

Comment: @ThePopMachine As a New Zealander I agree, European culture is by far the most dominant culture in New Zealand with sprinkles of Maori culture thrown in here and there primarily for taste and fear of not being PC. New Zealand is too western for this answer to be truly satisfying.

Comment: @Adrian773 : I appreciate your point, but when I answered the question it was not clear to me that "culture" was the main thing that ThePopMachine was driving at.  I figured he wanted to see a location outside North America / Europe or a human culture that is not European, but not necessarily *both* at the same time.

Comment: @Praxis Sorry, I didn't mean to say the answer was wrong. It's correct and a good interesting answer, it just does not truly satisfy.

Comment: @Adrian773 : No worries, I didn't take it as a criticism.  I just mean that I may have approached the question differently otherwise. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Earth) tells us a few things about what countries existed on Earth during the eras portrayed in Star Trek. These include the [African Confederation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/African_Confederation), a political entity with member states including Somalia, preceded by the [United States of Africa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_States_of_Africa), which was a country in the 23rd century.

However, the Memory Alpha pages on [Africa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Africa), [Asia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Asia), [South America](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/South_America), [Australia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Australia), and [Antarctica](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Antarctica) list various mentions of these locations throughout the series, but no actual appearances onscreen. I am forced to conclude that [Praxis's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107060/31394) is the only example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm asking about actual portrayal of a site, but just the mention that it exists.

Comment: A good list nonetheless.  +1

Comment: @ThePopMachine I've overhauled my answer to address your question better - what do you think now?

Comment: Not portrayed, but mentioned.  Spock was said to be Chinese, injured in a mechanical rice picker accident in City of the Edge of Forever.

Comment: Not sure if it counts, but Q took Picard and his crew to  medieval Nottingham in England

Comment: @Dave, well, that's fictional, holodeck, **and** Europe.